# How to make the child follow parent's rotation in qml

Tags: qt, 3d, qml

I want to render two 3d models with qml and control the rotation, the obj2 is the child of obj1, how to make obj2 follow obj1's rotation. I tried the qml like that(but i don't know how to assign the rotate angle of obj2), main.qml:

```
Item{
    Scene3D {
        id: scene3D
        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        focus: true
        aspects: "input"
    }
    obj1 {
            id: obj1
            obj2 {
                id: obj2
                 }
          }
   }
```

obj2.qml

```
Entity {
id: sceneRoot
Transform {
    id: j2Transform

    property real rotate_x : 0
    property real rotate_y: 0
    property real rotate_z : 0

    Scale {
        scale: 0.5
    }

    Rotate {
        id: rotate_x
        angle: // how to assign?
        axis: Qt.vector3d(1, 0, 0)
    }
    Rotate {
        id: rotate_y
        angle: // how to assign?
        axis: Qt.vector3d(0, 1, 0)
    }
    Rotate {
        id: rotate_z
        angle:// how to assign?
        axis: Qt.vector3d(0, 0, 1)
    }
    Translate {
        property real translation: 1
        dy: 0
    }
}

Mesh {
    id: j2Mesh
    source: "../res/obj/obj2.obj"
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: you cannot have property and item id with the same name.